# List has no rows for assignment to SObject: Publish

Tags: apex, class, list, apex-email-service

I have below line where I am getting Error as mentioned in subject header. Can some let me know the reason? Ideally it should return Email value.

```
String Emailing1 = [SELECT Email 
                    FROM User 
                    WHERE ID=:mycontact.Rep_abv__r.ManagerID].Email;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried to use the result of SOQL query in your code, but this result is not guarantied. In some case your query can return null. So, when you tried to use `null.Email` you got this error.

To fix it you need to check that query has returned an actual result.

```
User user1 = [SELECT Email 
              FROM User 
              WHERE ID=: mycontact.Rep_abv__r.ManagerID];
if (user1 != null) {
    String Emailing1 = user1.Email;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String Emailing1 = [select Email from User where ID=:mycontact.Rep_abv__r.ManagerID LIMIT 1].Email;
```

But you have to make sure the query returns values. Better you check the result for null and assign your values.

```
User myUser = [select Email from User where ID=:mycontact.Rep_abv__r.ManagerID LIMIT 1];
String Emailing1 = (myUser != null) ? myUser.Email : '';
```

Comment: You are trying to get size of a sobject rather than list - this will fail to compile. Using something like user[] myUser = [...] and then assigning using myUser[0].Email would be better.

Comment: Best would be just using ( ! myUser.isEmpty() ) ? ... : ... ;

Comment: agreed, I've added typical check for query result mistakenly

Comment: limit 1 is also redundant as IDs are unique! :)